# Misconception? Why does Javascript automatically execute variables?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm currently learning Javascript and I am wondering why the following executes "console.log('why')". I thought that 'variables' (var, let, const) only store information and cannot execute by themselves. I would not expect the following to actually preform the console.log.

```js
const x = console.log('why');

//likewise why would this work (granted if there was a button and an alert function)
function onClickFunction() {
    var myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 3000);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I think I am having a misconception about what can be accomplished using variables.

Comment: When you have a function call on the right side of an assignment statement, the variable is assigned to the return value of calling the function.

Comment: You. Can call a function and store returned result in a variabe, so console.log is a function

Comment: Maybe you wanted to do this: ``const x = () => console.log('why');``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because you have assigned to `x` the output of the function `console.log` when invoked with the parameter `'why'`.

If you want to assign a string to `x`, then you would do so using a [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) by expressing it in quotation marks like this:

```
const x = "some string";
```